# CSS Hover attribute reveal non-div element

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors

I want to be able to use the CSS hover element on each specific element within the div to affect each respective span element aka hovering on "something1" should reveal "text1" and so on.

Is it possible to accomplish this without adding a bunch of div's?

```css
span {
  display: none;
 }

.something1:hover .text1 {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <i class="something1"></i>
    <i class="something2"></i>
    <i class="something3"></i>
    <i class="something4"></i>
    <span class="text1">Show 1</span>
    <span class="text2">Show 2 </span>
    <span class="text3">Show 3</span>
    <span class="text4">Show 4</span>   
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest using Sass for this, but if you want to use straight up CSS, try this:

     .something1:hover .text1 {
      display: block;
      }

    .something2:hover .text2 {
      display: block;
      }

    .something3:hover .text3 {
      display: block;
      }

    .something4:hover .text4 {
      display: block;
      }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the CSS `~` general sibling selectors like this:

> The `~` combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent. - [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
span {
    display: none;
}
.something1:hover ~ .text1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <i class="something1">Something 1</i>
    <i class="something2"></i>
    <i class="something3"></i>
    <i class="something4"></i>
    <span class="text1">Show 1</span>
    <span class="text2">Show 2 </span>
    <span class="text3">Show 3</span>
    <span class="text4">Show 4</span>   
</div>
```

Select all `span` tags starting with "`text`x" class:

```css
span {
    display: none;
}
.something1:hover ~ span[class*="text"] {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <i class="something1">Something 1</i>
    <i class="something2"></i>
    <i class="something3"></i>
    <i class="something4"></i>
    <span class="text1">Show 1</span>
    <span class="text2">Show 2 </span>
    <span class="text3">Show 3</span>
    <span class="text4">Show 4</span>   
</div>
```

Comment: Correct, but i think the selector should be the other way around.

Comment: @user3329364 Select all `span` tags starting with "`text`-x" class - http://jsfiddle.net/3dpfd6ou/

Comment: `~` is not the "adjacent sibling selector", it's the "general sibling selector".